# remove empty dataframe from list and drop corresponding name in second list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I have two lists, where the first one is a list of strings called names and has been generated by using the name of the corresponding csv files.

```
names = ['ID1','ID2','ID3']
```

I have loaded the csv files into individual pandas dataframes and then done some preprocessing which leaves me with a list of lists, where each element is the data of each dataframe:

```
dfs = [['car','fast','blue'],[],['red','bike','slow']]
```

As you can see it can happen that after preprocessing a dataframe could be empty, which leads to an empty list in dfs.

I would like to remove the element from this list and return it's index, so far I have tried this but I get no index when printing `k`.

```
k = [i for i,x in enumerate(dfs) if not x]
```

The reason I need this index is, so I can then look at removing the corresponding index element in list `names`.

The end results would look a bit like this:

```
names = ['ID1','ID3'] 
dfs = [['car','fast','blue'],['red','bike','slow']]
```

This way I can then save each individual dataframe as a csv file:

```
for df, name in zip(dfs, names):
    df.to_csv(name + '_.csv', index=False)
```

**EDIT: I MADE A MISTAKE: The list of lists called dfs needs changing from [''] to []**

Comment: `if not x` will not result in True as the list has a value `['']`. The condition `if not x` will get triggered only if the list was `[]` without anything inside.

Comment: Removed pandas since nothing relate to pandas

Comment: your for loop `for df, name in zip(dfs,names)` is just a loop of lists. So `df` is not really a dataframe. The line inside the for loop `df.to_csv(name +...)` will NOT work. Are you sure it will work?

Comment: @JoeFerndz yes this part of the code works.

Comment: But then your `k = [i for i,x in enumerate(dfs) if not x]` should work, right?

Comment: @AnnZen no it still doesnt - I tried all methods that have been suggested and it is driving me insane... the output is still just an empty list and no index

Comment: @msa Does my edit help?

Comment: if list of lists ends up with `[]` instead of `['']`, then your code `k = [i for i,x in enumerate(dfs) if not x]` should work. What is not working?

Comment: please change it to `k = [i for i,x in enumerate(dfs) if x]` Thats the mistake you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) method:

```
k = [i for i, x in enumerate(dfs) if not any(x)]
```

The reason your

```
k = [i for i, x in enumerate(dfs) if not x]
```

doesn't work is because, regardless of what is in a list, as long as the list is not empty, the [truthy value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/13552470) of the list will be `True`.

The `any()` method will take in an array, and return whether *any* of the elements in the array has a truthy value of `True`. If the array has no elements such, it will return `False`. The thruthy value of  an empty string, `''`, is `False`.

**EDIT:** The question got edited, here is my updated answer:

You can try creating new lists:

```
names = ['ID1','ID2','ID3'] 
dfs = [['car','fast','blue'],[],['red','bike','slow']]

new_names = list()
new_dfs = list()

for i, x in enumerate(dfs):
    if x:
        new_names.append(names[i])
        new_dfs.append(x)

print(new_names)
print(new_dfs)
```

Output:

```
['ID1', 'ID3']
[['car', 'fast', 'blue'], ['red', 'bike', 'slow']]
```

If it doesn't work, try adding a `print(x)` to the loop to see what is going on:

```
names = ['ID1','ID2','ID3'] 
dfs = [['car','fast','blue'],[],['red','bike','slow']]

new_names = list()
new_dfs = list()

for i, x in enumerate(dfs):
    print(x)
    if x:
        new_names.append(names[i])
        new_dfs.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using enumerate , you do not have to loop again.

Hope this solves your problem:

```
names = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']
dfs = [['car', 'fast', 'blue'], [''], ['red', 'bike', 'slow']]


for index, i in enumerate(dfs):
    if len(i) == 1 and '' in i:
        del dfs[index]
        del names[index]

print(names)
print(dfs)

# Output
# ['ID1', 'ID3']
# [['car', 'fast', 'blue'], ['red', 'bike', 'slow']]
```

Comment: be careful, if there are many values and one of it happens to be `''`, it might delete the index

Comment: I figured that might be a problem. I haven't used pandas much, i assumed it would be '' always if its empty.

Comment: Also, try not to manipulate a list while you are iterating through it using for loop

Answer (score 0):

I think The issue is because of `['']`.

```
l = ['']
len(l)
```

Gives output as `1`. Hence,

```
not l
```

Gives `False`

If you are sure it will be `['']` only, then try

```
dfs = [['car','fast','blue'],[''],['red','bike','slow']]

k = [i for i,x in enumerate(dfs) if len(x)==1 and x[0]=='']
```

this gives `[1]` as output

Or you can try with `any(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the data presented, I would do the following:

Step 1: Check if list has any values. If it does, `if df` will be `True`.

Step 2: Once you have the list, create a dataframe and write to csv.

The code is as shown below:

```
names = ['ID1','ID2','ID3'] 
dfs = [['car','fast','blue'],[],['red','bike','slow']]

dfx = {names[i]:df for i,df in enumerate(dfs) if df)}

import pandas as pd
for name,val in dfx.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame({name:val})
    df.to_csv(name + '_.csv', index=False)
```